# UIViewController behind UINavigationController Bar - the correct way

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am doing my UI in code and I have come to the problem, that my `UIViewController` rides up behind my `UINavigationController`'s bar.

I googled a bit and there seem to be three solutions. Everything is however referring to the transition from iOS 6 to iOS 7 and it all seems a bit like a hack. I can't imagine that this is still the way it has to be done.

The solutions are removing the translucency, which I don't want to do. At one point in time I might want content to be scrolled and then show up faintly blurred in the background of the navigation bar. The other solution is to move everything down by adding "fake" padding. This is also not ideal, since I don't know if my content won't one day extend beyond the screen and then as mentioned earlier I would like to have the content go behind the navigation bar. Then there is the last solution `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None` which seems awfully like a hack.

Maybe it is however due to the way I initiate my `UIViewController` so I'll add the code I use in my `AppDelegate` here:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

     window = UIWindow()

     if let window = window {
         window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

         let vc = CustomUIViewController()
         navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:vc)

         if let _ = navigationController {
             window.rootViewController = navigationController
         }
         window.makeKeyAndVisible()
     }
     return true
}
```

Currently I am using the `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None` in `viewDidLoad()` work-around, but it doesn't feel right.

Thanks for any advice on how to correctly deal with this problem.

Comment: If the first subview of your UIViewController is a UIScrollView you can set automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets to YES and the scrollview should be inset nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing whatever wrong with setting the extended edges to None - that's what this setting is *for*.

Another very nice approach if your content is effectively static is to use Auto Layout and pin the top of your view controller's main view's subviews to the view controller's top layout guide. The bottom of the top layout guide is positioned automatically to match the bottom of the navigation bar when it is present. This the "modern way". It has the advantage that it keeps working when the navigation bar vanishes (i.e. in landscape).

If your content is a scroll view, then set the contents insets so that even though the scroll view *itself* extends up behind the navigation bar, the top of its *content* is fully visible when the scroll view scrolled all the way to its top. The runtime will actually do this for you automatically by default.

Comment: could you give an example for the second approach?

Comment: I had found this link in the past: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html The problem ist that I am not using IB and I tried solving it with help of `topLayoutGuide` mentioned in the discussion in `UIViewController`s Class Reference but I was unsuccessful. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide

Comment: this i.e. did not give the desired result: `oneOfMyViews.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92104/discussion-between-joseph-and-matt).